# Releasing Variable used by WebService

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I release a Variable that is being used by the WebService.

I'm using this form:

```
 HttpPrincipal.WSDLLocation: = FrmPrincipal.edtWS.Text;
 HttpPrincipal.Service: = 'CADServicesService'; 
 HttpPrincipal.Port := 'CADServices';     
 Trinity: = HttpPrincipal as CADServices;
```

At the moment when I will close the Form appears an error, and discovered that when I declare this part:

```
Trinity: = HttpPrincipal as CADServices;
```

I think it is getting stuck in memory.

The error is the following:

> "Invalid Pointer"
>   The error happens when you close the form, does not have any event in the OnClose or OnDestroy form.

Descriptions:
     `Trinity : CADServices,`
     `HttpPrincipal is a THTTPRIO,`
     `CADServices is my Unit containing all procedures / functions from WebService.`

Comment: Trinity must destroy the variable, the code is real yes, "CADServices" is the unit with my WebService.

Comment: Jose Eduardo, he meant that `Trinity := HttpPrincipal the CadServices;` resembles some pseudocode rather than real Delphi code.

Comment: My excuse was a mistake, the code would

 `Trindade := HttpPrincipal as CADServices; `

Comment: I hope that nobody will help you until you edit your question and fix all the mistakes. The details matter. Fix the actual errors. Post real code not fake code. Fix the formatting.

Comment: Also add the definitions for HttpPrincipal and CadServices, we can't read what's on your screen.

Comment: I edited the question, got better?

Comment: Better now. Use the debugger. Enable Debug DCUs and look at the call stack when the exception is raised. What is happening?

Comment: Jose, can you show the part where you create HttpPrincipal?

Comment: Excuse the ignorance @ David Heffernan, how active it?

@ whosrdaddy is being created at Design Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the designtime component try to create HTTPRIO at runtime:

```
function GetCadServices(Addr : String): CadServices;
const
  defSvc  = 'CADServicesService';
  defPrt  = 'CADServices';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)  
  try
    Result := (RIO as CadServices);
    RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
    RIO.Service := defSvc;
    RIO.Port := defPrt;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
Trinity := GetCadServices(FrmPrincipal.edtWS.Text);
```

If you imported the WSDL with the WSDL importer this code is automatically generated for you (look in the CadServices1 unit)

Comment: No avail, it is worth remembering that
Trinity: = HttpPrincipal as CADServices;

this being called in the main Form OnCreate

Comment: @JoseEduardo Like I said before, As long as you are leaving out details like these, chances are slim you will get a good answer

Comment: But it should not be freed if the owner of HttpPrincipal is set. More code will sure be helpful - especially related to creation and destroying of HttpPrincipal

Comment: @SirRufo: as stated in the comments under the OP's question it is a designtime component

Comment: Can you show me where this is stated? Maybe i'm blind ... but i can't find it ...

Comment: "talk to me like to a dog, but a little bit slower" :o) but if so, this instance will not be freed, because of existing owner. Maybe he mixed that up ;o) and we can't prove without the code

Comment: Thanks @ whosrdaddy.

The solution was to create the component at run-time-and he worked

grateful